# A do-nothing "job"

Tags: professionalism

I've worked here for about six months now, 8-5 just like a real job. Although, I say "worked" in the loosest sense, because I have consecutive days, even full weeks, where I sit with nothing to do all day.

I've asked several times for more tasks, and I'm either told to just "hang in there, things are coming soon" or dismissed saying we'll talk about it later. So much later that the boss is in his car driving home. I feel so underutilized.

Would it be a good idea to ask to "work" from home or leave early on days (emphasis on the plural) where I'm completely not doing anything?

Comment: It sounds like it is time to take some initiative and find a way to help the company.

Comment: "would it be a good idea to ask to "work" from home or leave early" - keep in mind the current value of being present. People will see you there and perceive that you're adding value. If you work from home all of a sudden, that perception may change to your detriment.

Comment: This seems like an odd closure reason to me "would it be a good idea to ask to "work" from home or leave early on days (emphasis on the plural) where I'm completely not doing anything?" seems like a real question with a real answer.

Answer (score 23):

This is a very bad idea.  If you can't afford to quit, you can't afford to be fired so don't bring attention to how expendable you are.  Find something you can do to provide value.  Without knowing the nature of the business or your skill set it's difficult to make suggestions but maybe learn skills in high demand in your workplace or ask to job shadow someone who does something that interests you.

Comment: Yes, he should either start marketing or doing other things to tie himself to the revenue stream.  If you're bringing in business, you'll never get fired

Answer (score 13):

You have a camera and digital photos don't cost you anything. Learn how to use it right. Learn what your company does and what it needs. Ask other people who look stressed and overworked what they might need help with.

Maybe they are testing your initiave? :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with learning more about what you do.  No matter what field you are in or what skill level, there are always ways to develop your skills.  At my programming job when things get slow, I read up on new developments in the field and see if I can implement them.  At my teaching job when things get slow, I try to develop fun new lessons... or I read up on new developments in the field, blah blah blah.  Sure I slack sometimes too, but too much slacking feels horrible.

Answer (score 3):

Working form home has the attached stigma of being a slacker. It is okay every once in a while but if you say things like "I don't have anything to do in the office anyway", you attract the attention of all people that you don't need attention from. If you **need** this job, my advice is trying to find ways of making yourself useful, or at least suck it up and show up between 8 and 5 daily to keep collecting your paycheck.

Comment: In some professions, notably software development, working from home is sometimes the only way to get things done. Especially if the office is an open-plan one, at worst shared by sales people that call and chat all day.

Answer (score 0):

Learn a new skill, work as a freelancer, do something productive. If I didn't have anything to do, I'd probably work on some of my own projects. If I were you I'd put up a freelance advertisement and do some work on the side. All my suggestions are good because you can always put them aside when your company tasks you with something.

Comment: Doing freelance projects on company time needs to be authorized by HR. I can't imagine any HR department authorizing that. If you ask them they are much more likely to let you go because you are not needed.

Comment: I'd +1 if it said "Learn a new skill, work as a freelancer, do something productive. If I didn't have anything to do, I'd probably work on some of my own projects... **outside of company time**"

Comment: @RobertDundon Well It's free company time ... He doesn't have anything to do, he's asked for work and not've been given by the management ... And he's been told by the above to just sit and wait for work to come ... Given the alternative is to literally sit on his chair and blankly stare at the most interesting dot on the wall ....